# Header was shaking when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, sticky

Note: Please try to use mousewheel when scrolling down. Also please be nice to mousewheel. Move it slowly.

I have a little question about scrolling. I am trying to reduce the header height when page scrolled to the down as most creative websites do. 
But in this case when I was tried to scroll down with mouse screen was shaking. Also sometimes its do with scrolling with mousewheel. All files added to the js fiddle. Please look at jsfiddle below. I hope I can express myself. Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 30) {
      $('.header-bottom').addClass('sticky');
      $('.header-bottom').css('line-height','80px');
    } else {
      $('.header-bottom').removeClass('sticky');
      $('.header-bottom').css('line-height','160px');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.header-top {
  line-height:30px;
  background: blue;
}
.header-bottom {
  line-height:160px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transition: .45s;
  -moz-transition: .45s;
  -ms-transition: .45s;
  -o-transition: .45s;
  transition: .45s;
}
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.content > div {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-top">Content</div>
<div class="header-bottom">Content</div>
<div class="content">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora nobis, suscipit consequuntur! Neque modi libero praesentium rerum, pariatur, assumenda obcaecati laudantium officia iste excepturi, molestias quibusdam quae sed nihil laborum.</div>
  <div>Necessitatibus, omnis odit ipsam, repudiandae beatae minima! Voluptates molestias vitae fuga officiis, aperiam earum quas laboriosam cupiditate hic vero reiciendis, numquam corporis, assumenda rem iure expedita animi magnam perferendis delectus.</div>
  <div>Eum odit hic delectus vel facilis nisi cupiditate ad enim recusandae ex, commodi sunt ullam distinctio, architecto quam nulla cumque possimus nihil qui unde magni provident ratione obcaecati fuga. Beatae.</div>
  <div>Iusto repellendus dolore atque architecto consequatur magni nulla animi possimus reiciendis, soluta similique recusandae voluptate reprehenderit, aspernatur repellat ab provident facere magnam sit unde, accusantium explicabo. Ducimus odit aliquid, minima!</div>
  <div>Et cum sapiente placeat quis. Aut nobis ea amet aliquid, voluptatibus laudantium, atque doloremque accusantium nulla iste tempore nemo. Totam non eos distinctio. Quaerat, dolorem, possimus. Dolores molestiae nam natus.</div>
  <div>Et cum sapiente placeat quis. Aut nobis ea amet aliquid, voluptatibus laudantium, atque doloremque accusantium nulla iste tempore nemo. Totam non eos distinctio. Quaerat, dolorem, possimus. Dolores molestiae nam natus.</div>
  <div>Et cum sapiente placeat quis. Aut nobis ea amet aliquid, voluptatibus laudantium, atque doloremque accusantium nulla iste tempore nemo. Totam non eos distinctio. Quaerat, dolorem, possimus. Dolores molestiae nam natus.</div>
  <div>Et cum sapiente placeat quis. Aut nobis ea amet aliquid, voluptatibus laudantium, atque doloremque accusantium nulla iste tempore nemo. Totam non eos distinctio. Quaerat, dolorem, possimus. Dolores molestiae nam natus.</div>
  <div>Et cum sapiente placeat quis. Aut nobis ea amet aliquid, voluptatibus laudantium, atque doloremque accusantium nulla iste tempore nemo. Totam non eos distinctio. Quaerat, dolorem, possimus. Dolores molestiae nam natus.</div>
  <div>Et cum sapiente placeat quis. Aut nobis ea amet aliquid, voluptatibus laudantium, atque doloremque accusantium nulla iste tempore nemo. Totam non eos distinctio. Quaerat, dolorem, possimus. Dolores molestiae nam natus.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see no shaking elements...

Comment: Works fine for me too on Firefox. Which browser do you use?

Comment: Please move scroll bar with mouse wheel slowly.

Comment: I see the issue, you need to use the scroll bar with the mouse slowly and not scroll down with the mouseweel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add `<div class="header">`. After `header-top` and `header-bottom` move into `<div class="header">`

And add css;
`.header { height:190px;}`

If you using `position:fixed` insted `position:sticky` this could be useful.

The problem will be solved.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 30) {
      $('.header-bottom').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
      $('.header-bottom').removeClass('sticky');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  height:190px;
}
.header-top {
  line-height:30px;
  background: blue;
}
.header-bottom {
  line-height:160px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -ms-transition: .5s;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  line-height:80px;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.content > div {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.margin {
  margin-top:190px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="header-top">Content</div>
  <div class="header-bottom">Content</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora nobis, suscipit consequuntur! Neque modi libero praesentium rerum, pariatur, assumenda obcaecati laudantium officia iste excepturi, molestias quibusdam quae sed nihil laborum.</div>
  <div>Necessitatibus, omnis odit ipsam, repudiandae beatae minima! Voluptates molestias vitae fuga officiis, aperiam earum quas laboriosam cupiditate hic vero reiciendis, numquam corporis, assumenda rem iure expedita animi magnam perferendis delectus.</div>
  <div>Eum odit hic delectus vel facilis nisi cupiditate ad enim recusandae ex, commodi sunt ullam distinctio, architecto quam nulla cumque possimus nihil qui unde magni provident ratione obcaecati fuga. Beatae.</div>
  <div>Iusto repellendus dolore atque architecto consequatur magni nulla animi possimus reiciendis, soluta similique recusandae voluptate reprehenderit, aspernatur repellat ab provident facere magnam sit unde, accusantium explicabo. Ducimus odit aliquid, minima!</div>
  <div>Et cum sapiente placeat quis. Aut nobis ea amet aliquid, voluptatibus laudantium, atque doloremque accusantium nulla iste tempore nemo. Totam non eos distinctio. Quaerat, dolorem, possimus. Dolores molestiae nam natus.</div>
  <div>Et cum sapiente placeat quis. Aut nobis ea amet aliquid, voluptatibus laudantium, atque doloremque accusantium nulla iste tempore nemo. Totam non eos distinctio. Quaerat, dolorem, possimus. Dolores molestiae nam natus.</div>
  <div>Et cum sapiente placeat quis. Aut nobis ea amet aliquid, voluptatibus laudantium, atque doloremque accusantium nulla iste tempore nemo. Totam non eos distinctio. Quaerat, dolorem, possimus. Dolores molestiae nam natus.</div>
  <div>Et cum sapiente placeat quis. Aut nobis ea amet aliquid, voluptatibus laudantium, atque doloremque accusantium nulla iste tempore nemo. Totam non eos distinctio. Quaerat, dolorem, possimus. Dolores molestiae nam natus.</div>
  <div>Et cum sapiente placeat quis. Aut nobis ea amet aliquid, voluptatibus laudantium, atque doloremque accusantium nulla iste tempore nemo. Totam non eos distinctio. Quaerat, dolorem, possimus. Dolores molestiae nam natus.</div>
  <div>Et cum sapiente placeat quis. Aut nobis ea amet aliquid, voluptatibus laudantium, atque doloremque accusantium nulla iste tempore nemo. Totam non eos distinctio. Quaerat, dolorem, possimus. Dolores molestiae nam natus.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thats what i want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

do `position: fixed;` instead of `position: sticky;` in the sticky class

```js
 $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 30) {
      $('.header-bottom').addClass('sticky');
      $('.header-bottom').css('line-height','80px');
      $('.content').css('margin-top','120px');
    }else {
      $('.header-bottom').removeClass('sticky');
      $('.header-bottom').css('line-height','160px');
      $('.content').css('margin-top','20px');
    }
  });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.header-top {
  line-height:30px;
  background: blue;
}
.header-bottom {
  line-height:160px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transition: .45s;
  -moz-transition: .45s;
  -ms-transition: .45s;
  -o-transition: .45s;
  transition: .45s;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: .45s;
  -moz-transition: .45s;
  -ms-transition: .45s;
  -o-transition: .45s;
  transition: .45s;
}

.content > div {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-top">Content</div>
<div class="header-bottom">Content</div>
<div class="content">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora nobis, suscipit consequuntur! Neque modi libero praesentium rerum, pariatur, assumenda obcaecati laudantium officia iste excepturi, molestias quibusdam quae sed nihil laborum.</div>
  <div>Necessitatibus, omnis odit ipsam, repudiandae beatae minima! Voluptates molestias vitae fuga officiis, aperiam earum quas laboriosam cupiditate hic vero reiciendis, numquam corporis, assumenda rem iure expedita animi magnam perferendis delectus.</div>
  <div>Eum odit hic delectus vel facilis nisi cupiditate ad enim recusandae ex, commodi sunt ullam distinctio, architecto quam nulla cumque possimus nihil qui unde magni provident ratione obcaecati fuga. Beatae.</div>
  <div>Iusto repellendus dolore atque architecto consequatur magni nulla animi possimus reiciendis, soluta similique recusandae voluptate reprehenderit, aspernatur repellat ab provident facere magnam sit unde, accusantium explicabo. Ducimus odit aliquid, minima!</div>
  <div>Et cum sapiente placeat quis. Aut nobis ea amet aliquid, voluptatibus laudantium, atque doloremque accusantium nulla iste tempore nemo. Totam non eos distinctio. Quaerat, dolorem, possimus. Dolores molestiae nam natus.</div>
  <div>Et cum sapiente placeat quis. Aut nobis ea amet aliquid, voluptatibus laudantium, atque doloremque accusantium nulla iste tempore nemo. Totam non eos distinctio. Quaerat, dolorem, possimus. Dolores molestiae nam natus.</div>
  <div>Et cum sapiente placeat quis. Aut nobis ea amet aliquid, voluptatibus laudantium, atque doloremque accusantium nulla iste tempore nemo. Totam non eos distinctio. Quaerat, dolorem, possimus. Dolores molestiae nam natus.</div>
  <div>Et cum sapiente placeat quis. Aut nobis ea amet aliquid, voluptatibus laudantium, atque doloremque accusantium nulla iste tempore nemo. Totam non eos distinctio. Quaerat, dolorem, possimus. Dolores molestiae nam natus.</div>
  <div>Et cum sapiente placeat quis. Aut nobis ea amet aliquid, voluptatibus laudantium, atque doloremque accusantium nulla iste tempore nemo. Totam non eos distinctio. Quaerat, dolorem, possimus. Dolores molestiae nam natus.</div>
  <div>Et cum sapiente placeat quis. Aut nobis ea amet aliquid, voluptatibus laudantium, atque doloremque accusantium nulla iste tempore nemo. Totam non eos distinctio. Quaerat, dolorem, possimus. Dolores molestiae nam natus.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Explain why `position: fixed` is better than `position: sticky`, because I see same output as from OP example

Comment: I was try to made with fixed. But its hiding first div. Sticky pulls the first div "Lorem ipsum". Any suggestion for that?

Comment: @AliÖzen I don't have the perfect answer for your first question but it's most likely because elements with position sticky have a relation with the elements around them as for fixed elements they aren't restricted they have relation just with the window. Also I edited my answer you just have to change margin-top because the content div doesn't have a relation with the element above it anymore

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem perfectly. Nothing shakes now at least in newest Chrome (69.0.3497.100 (Build oficial) (64 bits))

Comment: Yes it worked little bit. I just want to combine them. Not shake. Not jumping div or hiding divs. Header must pull divs without shake. I am open any kinda solution.